# Central Limit Theorem Result explanation

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

If one is given a non-uniform random variable with density $p(x)$ its expectation and error (when one tries to estimate this expectation are):

$$\mathbb{E}[f(x)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)p(x) dx$$
and
$$\epsilon_N (f) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)p(x)dx - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Nf(x_n)$$

The CLT gives the following results (I do not know how these are arrived at, I need help with precisely these two statements):

$$\epsilon \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\phi\sigma_f$$
$$\sigma^2_f = \int_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x)-\bar{f})^2dx$$

$\phi$ may or may not be a standard normal here.